# How to pass output parameter with value in C#.net?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have created one proc which return two values as output that is userlogin and password, the output parameters allow null, when a user wants to create a new login, the userlogin will pass as null else will pass the userlogin with value.

proce wise it works fine. But while passing in C#.net while create it works fine, but while update it creates new userlogin instead of update.

Comment: Review your `SP` logic or edit the question with your `SP`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is in stored procedure logic, it doesn't have to do anything with output params.

You should decide whether to update or insert user login based on some input parameter.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Thanks for realizing this to me.